# Is it possible in socket buffer messages in disorder

Tags: netty

For example：
In client, only one long connection but there are many threads will write message to it.If first thread1 write partial bytes for message1 but not complete, then thread2 write some bytes for message2, last thread1 write rest bytes.Does it exist this kind of case?if not, how netty avoid this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty ensure that all operations are executed in the IO-Thread. So if you write from a different thread it will make sure the actual write is done from the IO-Thread. So the order is guaranteered.